# why does python not recognize what I am typing?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am using python 3 and it is not working. I want to write some code that confirms that my computer is working properly, so I made it to return if It recognizes that I typed 15, but it is not working.
here is my code:

```
print("type 15")
input = f
if f == 15:
    print("15")

    else: 
        print("not 15)
```

when I run it, python return "not 15" instead of "15" even if I typed 15 and pressed enter

Comment: That code won't even run, let alone do what you want it to do.

Comment: ```x="type 15: "```, then
```y=input(x)```

Comment: Here if you type 15 in input then it will return a `string 15` not a `integer 15`. So you have to specify the type of `f` as `int`. Now it will return "15". Just type `if int ( f ) == 15:` instead of `if f == 15:`

Comment: @RishabhSemwal, No do not do this kind of edits. Do not correct Op's code

Comment: @Vega He stated that his code runs on his pc and giving some output then I guessed that he misprints code in this site. Thats why I only fixed the indentation of code, not the original bug. And I give the solution of that bug in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
f = input("Type 15")
if f == "15":
  print("15")
else:
  print("not 15")
```

Input is a function that takes one argument of a string, which is the instruction for the user. In this case, that is why we put “type15” in parentheses after input.

The data type returned by the input will be a string, so it can only be equal to a string. So we need put quotes around the 15 in the if statement to make sure there are no problems comparing integers and strings. I think you understand the rest. If you are still confused, feel free to comment and ask.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation, if OP is confused by data types they will also be confused about your code

Comment: Edit your answer please, don't post as a comment

Comment: I appreciate the guidance. I am fairly new to answering other’s questions. I am usually the one asking for help.

Comment: It's a good answer, good job. I made some minor edits but overall a good explanation